# How to expose OData feeds using Power BI?

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, powerbi, dynamics-crm-online, powerbi-embedded

I currently have internal users using the inbuilt OData feed exposed by Dynamics 365 Online. I would like expose a portion of the feed to anonymous users, based on the results of a predefined query, e.g. all contracts created more than one year ago, and only particular columns.

I was hoping Power BI Online could be configured to act as an intermediary and expose OData feeds based off queries.

Is this possible? Or does Power BI Online only consume data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it’s not possible. Dynamics CRM feed need authentication to show entitled data. PowerBI cannot generate feeds just consumption for reporting & data visualizations.

Either you can develop your own open API in which some service account can be used to impersonate for accessing filtered Dynamics CRM dataset, PowerBI can consume that API.

Or some SQL/Exported excel file in onedrive can be used as data source.